# Haskell: Failing to connect to DBus as client on FreeBSD

Tags: haskell, ghc, freebsd, dbus, haskell-stack

I'm using this library to do this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus.
Here is a minimal example to reproduce it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack runghc --resolver lts-7.20 --install-ghc --package dbus
import DBus.Client
main = () <$ connectSession
```

When I try to start it I'm getting this error:

```
SocketError {socketErrorMessage = "Authentication failed", socketErrorFatal = True, socketErrorAddress = Just (Address "unix:guid=53252465d2726f11957f8b9d58de79ab,path=/tmp/dbus-jUIv1mTBAV")}
```

But using `dbus-send` utility I can make a request without any errors:

```
$ dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
method return time=1490977755.289281 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.44 serial=3 reply_serial=2
   array [
      string "org.freedesktop.DBus"
      string "org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_14512"
      string ":1.7"
... rest of the list was removed ...
```

I'm starting DBus daemon for session in `~/.profile` this way:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=`dbus-daemon --fork --session --print-address`
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

It is relevant only to **FreeBSD**, connecting to DBus works fine on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Probably it's a freebsd related issue ? Works fine on my Linux machine.

Comment: Do you really need to start dbus manually? Just put `dbus_enable="YES"` into `/etc/rc.conf` and then do `service dbus start`.

Comment: @Sibi that's right, that why I added "FreeBSD" to the topic, I also added comment about it at the end to make it be more obvious.

Comment: @arrowd I actually have this option in `/etc/rc.conf` but for some reason when I enter **openbox** session from **gdm** I have no `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` env variable set and when I try to start my app I get this error: `ClientError {clientErrorMessage = "connectSession: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is missing or invalid.", clientErrorFatal = True}`

Comment: @unclechu Yep, you are right. You can use **system** bus without any additional setup, but you have to do something to use session one. I'm using kdm4, so i have `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` defined automatically. Unfortunately, I don't know what's proper way to start session bus.

Comment: @unclechu Did you ever resolve this? I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: @codedmart Nope, I just dropped my experiments of using FreeBSD in 2017 due to this issue. I also have tried to ask on some freenode chat, maybe in #freebsd, also sent a mail to mailing list of FreeBSD as far as I remember (about 3 years passed) but no one had any ideas of how to fix it and what causes this. Maybe it makes sense to try it again after few years to check whether it has being fixed or not.